# Azure の環境設定を JSON 等でエクスポートすることは可能？

Tags: azure

#### 目標

Microsoft Azureのクラウド環境でつまづいた点を共有して、他の人にアドバイスをもらうために状態の共有や問題点の再現が出来るようにしたいと考えています。
手段として期待出来るものは、Azureの設定値をJSONエクスポートやGitHubでの共有を考えています。

#### これまで試したこと

しかし、Azureの設定のExportの仕方などのドキュメントはありません。
また、Microsoft公認の人は自分のやり方をよくGitHubにドキュメント化しています。
guestアカウントに希望する人を招待するやり方は必要な権限の付与があるため、あまり好ましくないと考えています。

#### 期待

もっと簡単に、設定値をAzureCLIなどで設定するだけで開発者プログラム環境などへ反映が出来ないでしょうか？そうすれば、他の人のエラーの再現が出来ることや対処までの工数が減ると思います。

Comment: 参考: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-import-export-data

Comment: "Microsoft の人が GitHub にドキュメント化している" と書かれていますが、実例があるならその URL も示しておくと、イメージが伝わりやすいと思います。

Comment: 一理あると思います。ただ、GitHubのURLって本人に許可なく掲示してもいいものなのかが不明だったため辞めました。ただ、公衆に公開している時点でURLの貼り付けは可能だったと反省しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

リソースをテンプレートとしてエクスポートする機能があります。こちらを使うのはいかがでしょうか。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal#export-template-from-a-resource-group

Comment: リンク先の内容を確認して「ARM テンプレート」が問題解決方法に合うのか確認してみます。概要を見ると目的と期待する結果と合致すると思います。